# Github API v3 JSON passing

Tags: json, api, github

how can I avoid the parsing errors for

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw' -XPUT -g 'https://api.github.com/repos/USER/l1/contents/PATH/FILENAME.json?ref=gh-pages&access_token=57eef6413b12cb439b837b8fc4751b3291650de1' -d '{
   "message": "update from api",
   "committer": {
     "name": "USER",
     "email": "USERe@MAIL.com"
   },
   "content": "[{"a": "aaa","b": "bbb"}]",
   "sha": "c321fe9f6418053ecb87eb3cd2518a4xdfc83ebf"
   }'
```

**Answer**:

```
{
  "message": "**Problems parsing JSON**",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/"
}
```

Instead of

```
"[{"a": "aaa","b": "bbb"}]"
```

I've tried

```
"[{\"a\": \"aaa",\"b\": \"bbb\"}]"
```

but then I get the following error:

```
{
  "message": "**content is not valid Base64**",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/"
}
```

Best,

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a forum. If you look at other questions and answers, you'll see that we don't edit questions and mark their titles as "SOLVED". Instead, you are expected to up-vote all answers that help, and accept the answer that best solves your problem by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Comment: Also, don't edit your question to drastically change what it is asking. Doing so will render all of the answers invalid or irrelevant. If you have more questions, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the URL to [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) given in the error response, you'll see that the content needs to be `Base64` encoded.